# Irfanview alternative

Tags: software-rec, images

I'm looking for some very simple image viewer with the following functionality:

- fast start
- next/previous navigation (in directory)
- full-screen mode
- reasonable format support
- keyboard controllable
- image re-size to fit screen (with maintaining aspect ratio)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two lightweight image viewers that offer this sort of simple functionality and still have configurable or scriptable interfaces are [feh](http://feh.finalrewind.org/) and [sxiv](https://github.com/muennich/sxiv).

Comment: `feh` looks great

Comment: `feh` is nice, but doesn't support GIFs. `sxiv` supports GIFs and static images.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is [qiv](http://spiegl.de/qiv/).

From the [home page](http://spiegl.de/qiv/):

> Quick Image Viewer
>   for Linux, Solaris(SunOS), FreeBSD and HP-UX
>   ... is a very small and pretty fast gdk/Imlib image viewer.
>
> Requires: gdk-2.0 and Imlib2. Policy: GNU GPL
>   Features:
>
> - moving & zooming image in fullscreen mode.
> - setting image as x11 background (centered,tiled,stretched..) with user settable background color
> - fullscreen viewing with a great statusbar
> - external "qiv-command" program support
> - screensaver mode
> - brightness/contrast/gamma correction
> - real transparency
> - maxpect (zoom to screen size while preserving aspect ratio)
> - scale_down (scale down to big images to fit screen size)
> - slideshow (with random order if you want)
> - filename filer
> - flip horizontal/vertical, rotate left/right
> - delete function (move to .qiv-trash/)
> - jump to image number x, jump forward/backward x images
> - exif autorotation
> - browse mode when launching from file manager

Answer (score 0):

check out: ***geeqie*** (a GTK based multiformat image viewer)

Comment: Care to say why people should check this out?