# What is the fastest way to view images from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, software-rec, images

The terminal is very fast and convenient way to quickly access directories and files (faster than find and click on the directory).

One thing that it cannot show in text-mode is "pictures".

What is a best way to view pictures (like you see images thumbnail in Nautilus) when you are working in the terminal (e.g. command `nautilus` or any program - but should be fast and convenient)?

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15771/irfanview-alternative

Comment: I just run a terminal emulator under my desktop enviroment. So you have the advantages of both at hand.

Comment: Gotta object to the close votes here as there is a substantial difference between the need to view images files *from* a (presumably GUI) terminal (this question) and the need to view them *on* the console (the other question).

Comment: I provide a list of pretty much all your options here in this Q&A: [How to get JPEG thumbnails quickly](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110923/how-to-get-jpeg-thumbnails-quickly/110926#110926)

Comment: how to do it from inside the terminal http://askubuntu.com/questions/97542/how-do-i-make-my-terminal-display-graphical-pictures

Comment: Stay in the terminal with [ranger](http://ranger.nongnu.org/screenshots.html).

Comment: Unfortunately there is no true terminal solution that works over SSH, the dream goal.

Answer (score 344):

The way to "double-click" on a file from the command line is `xdg-open`.

If you're on Gnome (probably, if you're using Nautilus), you can use `eog` directly, or any other image program (`feh` is quite good).

```
feh <image-name>
```

If you want to consult `image-name` file easilly.

Comment: `feh` even works with multiple URLs!

Comment: @Searene Yeah! Long life to `feh`. But I observe that `feh` has **no zoom** or any other function whatsoever. `eog`, however, is also lightweight and, in addition, it can *zoom*, *rotate* and browse the images in a folder :). Just for the people to know before they make a choice.

Comment: although `eog` is preinstalled in my ubuntu os, I still prefer `feh` coz it can be closed by `q` while `eog` and `xdg-open` can be closed by `esc`.

Comment: I used feh loong time ago and forgot all about it, came looking for it and found this post! I need to make feh -. my default image viewer again.

Comment: Actually, `feh` does have zoom, fullscreen, scroll etc. look at the man page

Comment: Note that `xdg-open` only accepts a single target to open.

Comment: @Searene: Does this work on Windows command prompt? I am using Windows cmd to ssh to linux based server and I want to locally display images saved in the remote machine. I am getting error that `feh ERROR: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?`

Comment: @pikachuchameleon you'll need to set up an X11 environment and forwarding. Have a look at [these instructions](https://superuser.com/a/119908/104286)

Comment: @pikachuchameleon... yes. it works fine. You need to run a Xserver. Look into `Xming`. There is some initial configuration necessary.. and there are tonnes of tutorials online. Once its set, it works very reliably

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus: `feh -F` shows the whole image fullscreen, maybe also try `feh -Z`

Comment: @serv-inc Yeah, you're right: there is a full-screen zoom functionality or a full-screen window enlargement, but that's it. I find it quite austere, but of course depends on the user's requirements ;). Be blessed.

Comment: feh is a joke...

Comment: Another advantage of feh is you can pipe output into it using `feh -`. For example `dot myfile.gv -Tpng | feh -`. eog cannot do that.

Comment: I benchmarked most of the methods in this thread. feh is in 1'st place, with an average display time of 19.9ms. (See my answer table on page 2 of the thread.)

Answer (score 169):

If you happen to have installed [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), you can use its very handy [display](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/display.php) command-line tool.

```
display path/to/picture.png
```

Comment: I personally prefer `feh`, but `display` is usually installed on web servers, where `feh` or other image browsers aren't installed.

Comment: display works great on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop and also on stock Raspbian. No installs required. TNX from 2017

Comment: Great, works even with stream: `curl https://example.com/image.jpg | display`

Comment: to install imagemagick, `sudo apt install imagemagick-6.q16hdri`, I used it to open `.ppm` file, `display path/to/file.ppm`

Comment: Display can be fast, but often is not. My benchmark results: display averages 25925ms. feh averages 19.9ms.

Answer (score 154):

I usually run `python -m http.server 8080` (in *python2*: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`) from a folder containing the image and view it from the browser at localhost:8080/path/to/image.jpg. Works great to browse and look at different image and text files in that same directory.

Edit: This method also works for remote boxes. Just run the python server as above, and if the ports are open you can connect to myserver.com:8080/path/to/image.jpg. If the server does not expose ports, you can set up an ssh tunnel with `ssh me@myserver.com -N -L localhost:8080:localhost:8080` and then view the images from your local browser at localhost:8080/path/to/image.jpg. Note this http interface is *much faster* than ssh -X.

Comment: Clever! Works like a charm and there's no need to type `/path/to/image.jpg`. Just open `localhost:8080` and click on the filenames.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, you can also add tunnels easily using PuTTY configuration! Then you can access it through a browser. **Awesome!**

Comment: I needed `python -m http.server` with Python 3

Comment: `x-www-browser /path/to/image` or `firefox /path/to/image`

Comment: awesome trick! exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Sweet. This worked for viewing an mp4 too!!

Comment: And then? Running python3 -m http.server starts the server but I cannot reach nothing from my local machine...

Comment: The OP asked for the fastest way, not just a way. Please add a benchmark time to get the image displayed so we can compare methods.

Answer (score 139):

I have created a tool that uses various unicode block graphics characters to improve the resolution (compared to the canonical 2 pixel per characterapproach taken by other solutions posted here). It also automatically displays images in a thumbnail mode if multiple images are provided as input.

Installation:

```
git clone https://github.com/stefanhaustein/TerminalImageViewer.git
cd TerminalImageViewer/src/main/cpp
make
sudo make install
```

Usage:

```
tiv <image(s)>
```

More details at the github project: https://github.com/stefanhaustein/TerminalImageViewer

Example screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, guess because of self-promotion? I think it's the best tool for the job though and the question is still relevant today.

Comment: It's a pity it doesn't work with `apt install`. Perhaps time to make a ppa? In any case, this package worked for me, while none of the others did (perhaps I used them in a wrong way). I needed to be able to view images in terminal (for instance, when I'm inside a Docker container) and not to call an image viewer from terminal. Thank you for your answer and I can only thank you more for creating this small, but valuable package!

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind creating a FR for a PPA on the github project? Perhaps somebody is happy to step in -- at least it won't be forgotten until I find some chunk of free time to look into that...

Comment: a snap will be easier for everybody: no ppa to setup for you, no ppa to add for the user -> http://snapcraft.io/

Comment: Nice tool @StefanHaustein ! I just created a PR to allow users to use it through Docker :-)

Comment: @DanieleDellafiore Any suggestions for organizing the make file to work with and without snap? currently it copies the binary to /usr/local/bin/tiv -- requiring root.... should I move this step out? Or should I make this the default destdir? https://github.com/stefanhaustein/TerminalImageViewer/blob/master/snapcraft.yaml

Comment: Ill look into it

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you for your great work! Snap exsists now: `sudo snap install --edge tiv`

Comment: Does not compile on Ubuntu 16.04 with gcc

Comment: @StefanHaustein Not sure why but it drops a compile error in lines 134/135 in the initialisation of arrays fgcolor & bgcolor `array must be initialized with a brace enclosed initializer`

Comment: @MehdiLAMRANI please file an issue on github with os/compiler/platform details

Comment: The snap has bugs. It's still recommended to clone it from git.

Comment: This is so cool! If you use mutt you can give it the ability to view an image attachment by adding to your `mailcap` something like: `image/jpeg; tiv %s; needsterminal`

Comment: The OP asked for the fastest way, not just a way. Please add a benchmark time to get the image displayed so we can compare methods.

Comment: Tiv runs 5.4x slower than catimg for the same resolution. Also, when downloading it with brew, it came with 390MB of bloat!

Answer (score 35):

No dependencies, one C file, one header file: [imcat](https://github.com/stolk/imcat)

Works on linux, macos, windows.
Automatically scales to terminal width, with quality down-sampling.

[image]

Comment: any idea why I can't find this with `apt-get`?

Comment: Because it is a repository on github.
clone the repository on your PC and type 'make' in the folder, that you have downloaded

Comment: @SridharSarnobat For now you can build from source, or get a pre compiled package using apt if you use my [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~b-stolk/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Hmmmm, I'm having some issues with your repos getting ignored even when I use `sudo apt-get update --allow-insecure-repositories`.  But I was able to build from source (I wish all build from sources were this easy!). I'll have to see whether it causes memory leaks like iTerm's image viewer. Thank you for creating this.

Comment: I find it to be unusable cause the quality is so low, I can't see anything in my plots

Comment: Could you please benchmark this so we can compare and see which method is the fastest?

Answer (score 32):

I guess [**feh**](http://feh.finalrewind.org/) would be the one you are looking for.

Although popping out a terminal-like window for picture display as mplayer does for video playing, **Feh** is still considered as a terminal-based picture viewer due to its command-intensive control style.

Answer (score 27):

If you're in pure terminal with framebuffer activated, I'd recommend [fbi](http://www.nongnu.org/fbi-improved/). It's always in my after-install *to do* list.

Otherwise, [eog](http://library.gnome.org/users/eog/stable/commandline.html.en) is the default picture opener in Gnome, as Kevin mentioned. Also, [Shotwell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotwell_%28software%29) seems to open pretty fast for me... I'm pretty sure there are hundreds. **:-)**

Comment: Thanks for this one - it's news to me. As an aside, googling lands me at *`fim's`* (self-styled framebuffer image viewer *improved* ) manpage only a few search results in. Dont know yet the difference.

Comment: Damn, it doesn't work over ssh. I get `not a linux console`

Answer (score 25):

If you're on OS X, iTerm 2 supports displaying inline images:

[image: iTerm2 inline image]

As you can imagine, this can be highly useful when you just want to display an image without going in and opening up Preview.app or having to open the Finder to the image and hitting spacebar on the image.

The feature is documented at [iTerm2's feature page](http://www.iterm2.com/images.html)

Comment: It's really laggy in my experience.

Comment: Works fine for me. No issues with lag. MBP/OSX 10.12.6

Comment: Could you please benchmark this so we can compare and see which method is the fastest?

Answer (score 20):

Surprised that the [Terminology](https://www.enlightenment.org/about-terminology) terminal emulator is not among the answers. As easy as `tyls` and then clicking on an image:

[image]

or someting like `tycat image.png`, for example:

[image]

Plus a lot more. An *old* video, almost 3 years ago, demonstrating Terminology 0.3: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ibPziLRGvkg#action=share.

Comment: If you need to view a single known image, `tacat` or `typop` are preferred. First one will embed image into terminal output, second will show it in popup window.

Comment: Great suggestion. If only it worked more smoothly over ssh X11.

Comment: Could you please benchmark this so we can compare and see which method is the fastest?

Comment: No real benchmark, but
`ls -l rekx_draft_logo_72dpi.png` : .. `136914` and `file rekx_draft_logo_72dpi.png` : 
`rekx_draft_logo_72dpi.png: PNG image data, 500 x 500, 16-bit/color RGBA, interlaced`. With `time tycat rekx_draft_logo_72dpi.png` it takes `real 0m0,027s, user 0m0,008s, sys 0m0,016s`.

Answer (score 14):

The [kitty terminal](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/) can display inside the terminal with the icat "kitten"

E.g.

`kitty +kitten icat /path/to/image`

Example:

[image]

The kitty documentation suggests creating an alias, e.g.

`alias icat="kitty +kitten icat"`

So that then you can simply do:

`icat /path/to/image`

Comment: Could you please benchmark this so we can compare and see which method is the fastest? The usertime reported by the time should work here.

Answer (score 13):

[w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/)'s imgdisplay library is able to display images directly. It only works on some terminal emulators such as Xterm and URxvt.

[ranger](http://ranger.nongnu.org/) is a file browser that makes use of the library to display previews.  Add this to ranger's configuration file to enable the feature:

```
set preview_images true
```

Comment: Could you please benchmark these so we can compare and see which method is the fastest?

Answer (score 11):

*From* the terminal?  Why not *in* the terminal: [`cacaview`](https://www.pc-freak.net/blog/viewing-jpeggif-and-png-in-ascii-with-cacaview-on-gnu-linux-short-review-on-caca-utils-text-mode-graphics-utilities/) might be the fastest.  By default it's fastest if the terminal has no graphics.

In Debian: `sudo apt-get install caca-utils`

Answer (score 9):

Actually, there is a way to show a PNG file in a terminal in text-mode, using picture-tube:

[image: screenshot]

You can look at the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/substack/picture-tube).

The image is of course an approximation of the actual image, given the fact that the smallest pixel is a character - try to have a look at the result in a text editor, you will see a huge number of color codes.

You can install the tool like this (assuming you have already installed node/npm):
`npm install -g picture-tube`

Answer (score 9):

There is a tool here called `catimg` that works really well:

https://github.com/posva/catimg

Also has deb packages on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/catimg

Answer (score 7):

Another great terminal-based picture viewer is [fim](http://www.autistici.org/dezperado/fim/), which is a improved fbi with a vim-like control system.

Comment: Good solution, but didn't show a way to do it.

Comment: I tried this. It opens a separate X window over SSH in case anyone's wondering. What would be ideal for me is an inline terminal display that works over SSH but I don't think there is a good one.

Answer (score 6):

The Ranger file manager enabling the image-preview in settings.
[image: Ranger file manager with image preview]

Comment: Ranger was already mentioned [5 years earlier](/a/163365)

Comment: and ranger appears to launch another program, it may work with inline, but I see it running the default image viewer: feh or imageviewer

Answer (score 5):

In linux you can install gnome-open.

```
# In Debian flavors

sudo apt-get install gnome-open
```

Then create an alias:

```
alias open='gnome-open'
```

Then you can:

```
open file.pdf
open file.jpg
etc
```

Comment: This was installed by default in my Ubuntu install.

Answer (score 5):

This is a 4 year-old-question but I found that people still look at it. So, today I would like to answer my own question specifically only for `iTerm2`.

At first time I asked this question. The term of **"fastest"** I was thinking of viewing image as fast as `cat` command displaying text. So, today I found the answer on `iTerm2`, which are the two handy commands name `imgcat` and `imgls`.

To use them, the first let's install `iterm2-nigthly`:

```
$ brew cask install iterm2-nightly
```

then visit the website:

https://github.com/olivere/iterm2-imagetools

and install `imgcat` and `imgls` commands:

```
$ go install github.com/olivere/iterm2-imagetools/cmd/imgcat
$ go install github.com/olivere/iterm2-imagetools/cmd/imgls
```

So, I really love them and also hope this will be useful for you all!

Comment: This _is_ very useful, so thanks for answering this 4 years later. Works like a charm, but might want to include the install go step (`brew install go`) for those that don't have it yet.

Comment: @jamescampbell, you don't need to install go to get the imgcat and imgls scripts. They're provided to you by iTerm's developer himself here: http://www.iterm2.com/documentation-images.html, and these are bash scripts.

Comment: what is the closest option to `imgcat` on Linux? I'm trying to switch atm

Comment: Could you please benchmark this so we can compare and see which method is the fastest?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [chafa](https://hpjansson.org/chafa/) ([on GitHub](https://github.com/hpjansson/chafa)). It has a [gallery with plenty of examples](https://hpjansson.org/chafa/gallery/), showing different options. It even supports animated GIFs.

[image: chafa animated GIF screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

[pxl](https://github.com/ichinaski/pxl) is a pretty cool option which hasn't been mentioned yet. Similar to picture-tube which was previously posted in that it shows the image directly in the terminal although it supports more image formats.

Answer (score 4):

I just use the Chrome webrowser, which supports `jpg`, `svg`, `png`, `ico`, animated `gif`... basically everything I'm likely to need:

```
google-chrome ./myphoto.jpg
```

If you prefer Firefox:

```
firefox ./myphoto.jpg
```

Comment: Could you please benchmark this so we can compare and see which method is the fastest globally?

Answer (score 2):

[img2sixel](https://github.com/saitoha/libsixel)

Fast, convenient, and easy to use.

To use:

```
$ img2sixel <image_name>
```

To install (ubuntu 18.04):

```
$ sudo apt install libsixel-bin
```

Example (scaled down to 400 pixels wide with -w 400):

[image]

There's a list of terminal requirements in the link, but it's worked with any terminal I've tried it on. I won't bother listing all the supported terminals, but here are some:

> DEC VT series, VT240/VT241/VT330/VT340/VT282/VT284/VT286/VT382
>
> DECterm(dxterm)
>
> Kermit
>
> ZSTEM 340
>
> WRQ Reflection
>
> RLogin
>
> mlterm
>
> Works on each of X, WIN32 GDI, framebuffer, Android, Cocoa version.
>
> XTerm (compiled with --enable-sixel-graphics option)
>
> yaft
>
> Mintty (>= 2.6.0)

Comment: This worked for me the best and it actually printed in a legible resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this page, and it is still very relevant today.  OP didn't really specify if they want X or fb viewer.

I use a small utility called pho: http://www.shallowsky.com/software/pho/

Needs X, so call from command line in a terminal window. Views many picture formats, gif and jpg for sure... some others as well.

Can do wildcard globbing from command line: eg. "$ pho img00??.jpg"  will view all files that match in order.  Space goes forward through list and backspace goes back.  Its quick loading individual images -- hold down space and you fly through them.

Very fast if you want to look through a bunch of pictures, flag ones of interest, rotate, delete unwanted... I keep coming back to it.

From the web page above:

> pho (pronounced like the first syllable in "photo") is a lightweight program for viewing large numbers of images quickly, rotating or deleting some, and making notes about what to do with each image -- for instance, for going through hundreds of images after uploading them from a digital camera.

Comment: Could you please benchmark this so we can compare and see which method is the fastest?

Answer (score 1):

Even tough there are great answers given, my issue was to view images in terminal itself, without openning any graphical application, so i wrote my own little script. I only needed to identify the image and did not need al the details of it and did not want to download any relatively big packet, if anyone needs they can also use it: 
https://github.com/Deniz97/terminal-image-viewer

Answer (score 1):

I have a shell alias for macOS called `preview` that can (1) display an image inline (`-i` or `--inline` option), either from stdin or specified filepath(s), and (2) just open an image in Apple's **Preview** app (without any option), the latter also either from stdin or filepath(s), e.g.:

`cat image.jpg | preview`

`preview -i image.png`

Inline display only works with the iTerm `imgcat` alias, so you need iTerm installed, running, and frontmost. But `preview` checks if all that is true.

Online here: https://github.com/JayBrown/Tools/blob/master/Aliases/preview

Answer (score 1):

If you have any relatively recent version of ImageMagick, you can output images to [any terminal emulator that supports the SIXEL format](https://www.arewesixelyet.com/). This is different from the ImageMagick `display` command, as the latter requires an X11 session and spawns a separate window, while the former works with any supported terminal, even over SSH. The following command takes an input image, converts it to a SIXEL image, and outputs it to stdout so the terminal emulator can render it:

```
convert input.png six:-
```

---

[image: A Konsole session displaying an image using ImageMagick SIXEL output]
<sub>Sample image: [Andy Reago & Chrissy McClarren](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:-_7715_%E2%80%93_Dryocampa_rubicunda_%E2%80%93_Rosy_Maple_Moth_(20309009618).jpg), [CC BY 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0), via Wikimedia Commons</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> What is a best way to view pictures (like you see images thumbnail in Nautilus) when you are working in the terminal [...] ?

This part of the question about **previewing multiple images at once** has not yet been addressed properly. Most image viewers (with the exception of [TerminalImageViewer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/377368)) will not show multiple thumbnails when called with multiple image files. They might display them in a slideshow, which is not always practical (e.g. when browsing through icons).

As a solution, I use a usual file manager in "thumbnail" mode to display all images that I copied to a temporary directory. For example, to display all icons from the KDE icon theme "Breeze" where the filename matches `*search*`:

```
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d -t image-previews-XXXXX)

find /usr/share/icons/breeze -name "*search*" -exec \
    bash -c '
        tmpdir=$1; 
        file=$2; 
        newfile=${file/\/usr\/share\/icons\/breeze\//}; 
        newfile=${newfile//\//-}; 
        cp $file $tmpdir/$newfile
    ' _ $tmpdir {} \; 

pcmanfm-qt $tmpdir
```

### Discussion

This `find`s and copies all Breeze icons matching `*search*` to a temporary directory, replacing the path relative to the Breeze installation directory with a filename that has `-` instead of the directory separator `/`. This way, the files are all in one directory for previewing, and won't overwrite each other.

Then this starts a file manager (here `pcmanfm-qt`) to show the files in the temporary directory. After it starts, it has to be manually set to thumbnail view for best results. Unlike other image viewers, file managers usually can render SVGs into preview thumbnails.

The `find` command uses a technique with positional parameters in a subshell to allow executing multiple commands in `find` including variable evaluation, as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5121324).

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Mint:

```
xviewer logo.png
```

Comment: Could you please benchmark this so we can compare and see which method is the fastest?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using plain text console (not even the framebuffer), then there is (still) zgv -
https://www.svgalib.org/rus/zgv/

It requires a PC compatible, though (i.e. i386 and VGA)

Answer (score 0):

- No X11 needed.
- Works in tmux.

```
git clone https://github.com/stolk/imcat.git ~/
cd ~/imcat
make
~/imcat Your_path_of_a_pic
```

[image]

Comment: Same as https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440521/70524

Comment: Yes, same tool. Just provide some information for convenience

Answer (score 0):

If you have `ffmpeg` installed, you can try the command `ffplay [/path/to/your/image] &>/dev/null`

`&>/dev/null` ignores the text output that's probably irrelevant if you just want to see the image.

Answer (score 0):

feh.

To determine the fastest, we must measure the time. Here are my times for opening and displaying a 700x500 pixel png benchmark image. I took 10 samples for each program. I'm using Ubuntu22.04 from Win11/WSLg with a 12th Gen Intel core i7-12800H. All times are in milliseconds.

| Program | avg | min | max | stdev | Measurement method | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| feh | 19.9 | 11 | 24 | 5.1 | user time | WINNER |
| [catimg](https://github.com/posva/catimg) | 24.3 | 23 | 26 | 1.0 | realtime | low resolution, in-terminal |
| dillo | 27.0 | 16 | 36 | 6.8 | user time | but must manually maximize window |
| [tiv default](https://github.com/stefanhaustein/TerminalImageViewer) | 105.0 | 95 | 113 | 5.4 | realtime | 5x10px thumbnail in terminal. 390MB brew download! |
| tiv -h 50 -w 150 | 132.3 | 117 | 156 | 11.1 | realtime | comperable to catimg but with compression artifacts. 390MB brew download! |
| eog | 333.3 | 206 | 631 | 158.3 | user time | yet nice |
| picture-tube | 1377.2 | 1321 | 1448 | 43.2 | wristwatch | terrible image quality, opens seperate window |
| gimp | 1422.1 | 1333 | 1483 | 57.5 | user time+system time | opens gimp, then loads image. These may be underestimated by 30-50%. |
| nautilus | 2633.3 | 2000 | 3500 | 522.0 | wristwatch | only get thunbnail |
| ffplay | 3055.6 | 2500 | 4000 | 583.3 | wristwatch | needs pipe to dev/null |
| display | 25925.6 | 57 | 98000 | 34239.5 | user time, wristwatch | UI buttons don't work |
| cacaview | 317888.9 | 5000 | 2748000 | 911341.2 | wristwatch | terrible image quality, opens seperate window |

Answer (score -2):

If using gnome it is as simple as typing

```
$ gnome-open /path/to/photo
```

and it opens the image using the default image viewer that you have in your machine.

Comment: Already posted a few months ago: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/248179/70524

Comment: this method will be very slow, if you have many images in the same folder with that image.