# How to use and display icon images in Linux terminal (like on OSX)

Tags: shell, prompt, icons

I discovered that it's possible to use "icon" in terminal (for eg in prompt) on OS X, [as it can be seen here:](http://osxdaily.com/2013/04/08/add-emoji-command-line-bash-prompt/)

[image]

Is it possible to do this on a regular Linux distribution (eg ubuntu) ?

Comment: I don't think it currently allows bitmaps in the prompt (utf8 chars are fine) but for an awesome terminal experience, have a look at Terminology in Enlightenment.

Comment: [Terminology](https://www.enlightenment.org/about-terminology) looks indeed very cool!

Comment: On same kind of topic, I found [TerminalImageViewer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35333/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-view-images-from-the-terminal/377368#377368) to display bigger image in terminal with "reasonable" resolution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are unicode symbols or emoji. Homebrew used to have a Beer Mug as a symbol in its output. As long as you have a font that supports them you will see them. On macOS you can go to the Edit > Emoji and Symbols... to insert them. Not sure of the equivalent on Ubuntu. You should be able to copy-and-paste them into your text editor from [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/#miscellaneous-symbols-and-pictographs).

Comment: For now, it seems that existing terminal [do not support color font](http://askubuntu.com/questions/781851/use-emoji-inside-terminal)

Comment: Try this: [How To See Full Color Emoji on Linux (Updated)](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/enable-color-emoji-linux-svg-font). I'll try it on my Ubuntu VM and let you know the results.